# Redux dispatch with Promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, es6-promise

I would like run multiple dispatch with Promise.

I've 2 action, **importSelfInfoFromApi** and **FlashMessage**. I would like this :

`store.dispatch(importSelfInfoFromApi()).then(() => store.dispatch(setFlashMessage('Synchronisation finished')));`

```
case 'IMPORT_SELF_INFO_FROM_API':
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    callApi('/users/me', 'get').then((result) => {
      resolve(store.dispatch(importSelfInfoFromApiSuccess(result))); // Success
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(store.dispatch(importSelfInfoFromApiError(error.message))); // Error
    });
  });
```

Do you know if i need to use `redux-thrunk` ? I can't just return Promise in my action ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 1):

From [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) docs:

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return
>   a function instead of an action.

So seems it's not what are you looking for. You need another one - [`redux-promise`](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) for handling promises in your actions